# submitting a curl command from an ec2 instance does not send credentials of the attached security profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-sns

I have an ec2 instance with a instance profile attached to it.  This instance profile has permissions to publish messages to a sns topic.  When I remote into the ec2 instance and issue a command like

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn topic_arn --message hello
```

This works.

Now I'm trying to do the same with a simple curl command and this is what I use after remoting into the ec2 instance

```
curl "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Message=hello&Action=Publish&TargetArn=topic_arn"
```

I get the following error

```
<Code>MissingAuthenticationToken</Code>
<Message>Request is missing Authentication Token</Message>
```

I was hoping that the curl would attach the instance profile details when sending the request (like when using the aws cli) but it does not seem to do so.  Does anyone know how I can overcome this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
curl "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Message=hello&Action=Publish&TargetArn=topic_arn"
```

you are directly making a request to the SNS endpoint. Which means that you have to [sign your request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) with AWS credentials from your instance profile. If you don't want to use AWS CLI or any AWS SDK for accessing the SNS, you have to program the entire signature procedure yourself as described in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

That's why, when you are using AWS CLI

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn topic_arn --message hello
```

everything works, because the AWS CLI makes a **signed request** to the SNS endpoint on your behalf.

Comment: thanks for this, so does that mean if I'm to use curl I cannot use the details of the intance profile and have to use a secret key combination ?

Comment: @tmpdev You can use instance details, but before you perform curl, you have to constract valid, signed url as explaiend in the docs.

Comment: I'm sorry but I went through the docs specifically https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html, but all I see is a reference to `your secret access key`.  It does not seem to mention how to use the instance profile.  Would be great if you can point me to the part of the doc which shows how to generate this using the instance profile.

Comment: @tmpdev Getting instance profile is a separate issue described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html).